# How do I use multiyear estimators in panel data?

Tags: regression, panel-data, estimators, census

I ran into this problem when trying to use data from the US Census Bureau. Their American Community Survey (ACS) has useful data that I want to include in a panel study of the years 2006-2019. They have single-year estimates for these data as well as multiyear estimates that track the variables in the same geography.

My question is this: is it possible to include multi-year estimators in a panel study? If so, how? Using 5-year estimates for any single year is obviously problematic and expressly warned against in the Census Bureau's manual (e.g. it would not be accurate to say that an observation from the 2015-2019 estimates is from "2017" even though it is the midpoint between the sampled years). I would just use the one-year estimates but they have a much greater margin of error and my goal is accuracy, not currency.

Take population: if I want to have a yearly count of population for a state - the population in 2006, the population in 2007, etc. - how can I do this with mutliyear estimates? Is it even possible?

Comment: Welcome to CV! The manual expressly indicates it is inappropriate to use the midpoint as an estimate of the resident population size? I think this is referring to labelling. In other words, you should be transparent about what estimate is being used. Is this a quote directly from the handbook?